# Read several times from pipe

Tags: c, file, pipe

I have two processes, one father and the other is the son, the son needs to access a text file, read it and send it to the father through a pipe, so he can print it. I don't know the size of the file so I guess the best way to do it is to send one line of the file at the time, but I dont know how to make the father known when to keep reading from pipe and when to stop.

Here's a sample of what I'm thinking:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <grp.h>
#include <dirent.h>

void main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    int pipes[2];
    pipe(pipes);
    pid_t son;

    son = fork();

    if(son ==0){
        FILE *file;
        char buff[1020];
        if ((file = fopen("path","r")) == NULL) printf("Error  %s\n",strerror(errno));
        close(pipes[0]);
        while (fgets(buff,1020,file) != NULL){
            write(pipes[1],buff,strlen(buff) +1);

        }}
    else{
        char *bufftemp = malloc(sizeof(char)*1024);

            close(pipes[1]);
            while (read(pipes[0],bufftemp,1024) != 0 ){
                printf("FATHER  %s",bufftemp );
            }
            free(bufftemp);
            printf("\n");
    }


    exit(0);



}
```

If I print the buff from the son, it prints each line, but the father seems to not read every time and it just reads the first line and thats it.

Comment: Closing the file/pipe would make it very clear where the end is.

Comment: How do you determine the gender of a process?

Comment: Why would you send one line at a time?  Either send it a character at a time, or a block at a time.  There's no need to waste time parsing the file looking for line breaks.

Comment: can you close and then open a pipe again? because the son keeps using the pipe after reading the file to make other things.@William I would use a `while(fgets() != Null)` to read each line

Comment: The child can write chunks of a convenient size to the pipe.  The parent will read chunks of a size convenient to it (not necessarily the same size as the child uses).  The parent needs to pay attention to short reads; that is, it might ask for 10 KiB but might only be given 1 KiB.  That's fine; it can process that however it likes (buffer it, if it wants to, or use what was sent) and then go back for more.  There's a finite size to the capacity of a pipe for holding unread data, and the child will block if it writes too fast, and the parent will block if it reads too fast.

Comment: If the child cannot close the pipe (this sounds like a design flaw), then you need some mechanism to indicate when the file ends.  Probably the easiest is to first write the size of the file, and then write the file.  However, it would be much better to change the design so that is not necessary.

Comment: You cannot close and then reopen a pipe; once closed, it is closed forever.  If you need to send multiple files over a single pipe, then you'll need to define a protocol such that the father knows when a new file is being sent, and when that file is complete.  This will require some care.  You should aim to send the file size as part of the first packet.  Failing that, you should have a message that says 'first chunk of new file', 'next chunk of current file', and 'last chunk of current file', followed by a size (which might be 0 for the last chunk), and then the data for the chunk.